# Antique tool identification

Tags: tool-identification

Can anyone identify the tools in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: If you don't find your answer here, consider reddit for "what is this thing" https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/

Comment: tools for making leather harnesses ?

Answer (score 1):

These are leather carving tools.

I had just assumed they were some kind of woodworking tools because they were being auctioned and the catalog described them as woodworking tools, which was incorrect. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like stonemason tools. The toothed chisels in the left hand side are common texturing masonry chisels, and the mushroomed handles plus hammer imply these are struck with a lot of force multiple times. Woodworking chisel handles rarely show mushrooming.

Not sure about the two pliers-like tools, the small toothed wheels or the thin goosenecked tools.